# Autocrafting table in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hi i was just wondering if it is posible to make an automatic crafting table in vanilla Minecraft. (But not [Colored Carrot's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLE5o4WAVeE) creation, that's not what I'm looking for.)

Comment: I'd recommend trying Tekkit, the autocrafting table in it is pretty good. I was able to set up a factory that you put materials in chests at one end of the room and it went through a series of autocrafting tables and ended up with a finished product.

Comment: Do you know what *vanilla* minecraft means? It means *no mods*. So tekkit isn't an option, as it is a **mod**pack. Pay attention to the OP. This isn't constructive or helpful to anyone here.

Comment: In response to the OP, it might be possible using some scoreboard and blockdata magic, but you would need to program every recipe you want it to work for by hand, not an ideal situation (hence not an "answer") but could work fine for limited operations. It essentially follows the same principles as vanilla custom crafting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BETTER ANSWER:

The way it works is, not like a real auto crafting table, but one that autocrafts a certain recipe, the one we have is cake. We use a detect command to see if a cow is on a certain block on a certain place, and it tests for this every 30 seconds. If it detects a cow it will use the execute command then the blockdata command to put a milk bucket in a chest, the milk bucket is then transported to our autocrafting area.

We have a sugar cane farm and also a egg farm and wheat farm(using a villager).

Once all the items are in the room the process begins. It first starts with sugar, the sugarcane is transported into a dropper, into a hopper into a chest, there is a delay letting the item in the hopper go in which a comparater is powered, activating a command block which uses the blockdata command to put 1 sugar in a chest per sugar cane.

The sugar is taken out of the chest and goes into a dropper which is on a fast clock, that throws it into another hopper using the same delay system the sugar does. Each time the comparater is activated, three milk buckets are dropped onto another one of the hoppers using the same delay system(from a dropper which the milk from the first thing i talked about is transported), which drops three wheat, which when three have been dropped into the hopper then in turn drops an egg(all of this is from items transported from the farms).

Once the delay hopper system has activated from the egg a command block is activated, which uses the blocksata command to put 1 cake in a chest, which is taken to the storage room then transported to the automatic shop.
Wow that was long.

Comment: Its good you could do it, however i'm downvoting your answer since is not clear enough to be helpful for others who may be in the same situation; your current answer would fit better as a comment unless more detail is added

Comment: I am rather sure that there is no "detect" command. Do you mean the /testforblock or are you just looking for attention? I see no way of doing it as an interface would be randomised, as far as i know

Comment: There is a detect command which detects for entities on a certain block of your chosing in a certain place. The explanation is pretty vague here so i will elaborate further.

Comment: @jclozano is that better

Comment: This is a massive run on. Please organize your thoughts and break it out into discrete paragraphs.

Comment: paragraphed it all

Comment: That looks nicer :); could be improved with references, since not everyone knows about all the commands or concepts described

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible in vanilla Minecraft. The crafting table has no native interaction with any kind of machinery, redstone or otherwise.

For reference, [here is the link to the Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Crafting_Table) Crafting table. No mention of autocrafting.

Comment: He was probably wondering if you could do it using command blocks, hence the "minecraft-commands" tag.

Comment: Yeah thats what i was aiming at XD

Comment: Ah, might want to update your question then to be more specific. I'm not too familiar with the minecraft-commands aspect of the game.

Comment: If you need help, websites like MCStacker or Gamepedia can help you massively